# Visual Studio 2017 - Exporting Template is blank

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have created a Class Library titled 'ClassLibrary3' which is targeting NET Standard 1.4, it contains one class and one simple method that returns "Hello World" as a string, like so.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I then exported this as a Project Template via the Project -> Export Template option, the end result is an archive containing all files within the project folder including the Class1.cs file, however the template itself in Visual Studio does not load the code files
[image: Visual Studio Project]

This is how the archive created from the export process looks
[image: Exported template archive]

The csproj XML is the following

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I have looked online and found [these Xamarin templates](https://github.com/kkbruce/Xamarin.Forms-.NETStandard-Project-Templates/tree/master/Templates) but they don't seem to be using the Visual Studio 2017 csproj template, the next piece I found is an issue raised via this [DeveloperCommunity issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/21751/creating-new-project-from-vs-2017-rc-exported-temp-1.html)

Has anybody been able to successfully create a Project Template on Visual Studio 2017 or is this something we're awaiting a fix for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exported project template in VS2017 misses source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553375/exported-project-template-in-vs2017-misses-source-files)

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

http://irisclasson.com/2017/06/14/visual-studio-2017-templates-and-the-missing-content/

It worked to me after one day of searches.