# Exported project template in VS2017 misses source files

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2017, project

When I use the `Project -> Export template` option in Visual Studio 2017, the resulting ZIP file includes the main project files, but not any of the `*.cpp` and `*.hpp` files that I've added. How do I include everything with the template? I should also note that this behavior seems to have changed in an update at some point.

Comment: VS 2017 has inbuilt CMake. You can alternatively use it to create CMakeLists.txt file for your project which will help to rebuild the project in another system. It works like charm in conjunction with git also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to manually edit the **.vstemplate** file and add `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` in the `<TemplateData>` tag so it looks like this:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>TemplateTest</Name>
        <Description><No description available></Description>
        <ProjectType>JavaScript</ProjectType>
        <ProjectSubType>
        </ProjectSubType>
        <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
        <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
        <CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
        <DefaultName>CodovaTemplateTest</DefaultName>
        <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
        <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
        <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
        <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
```

Comment: Adding `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` in the `<TemplateData>` works to [fix a similar problem](http://irisclasson.com/2017/06/14/visual-studio-2017-templates-and-the-missing-content/) which arises when exporting a C# .NET Core template, but it doesn't seem to work when exporting a C++ template.

[Hawkeye5450's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48966864/4579181) fixes the bug when exporting a C++ template.

Comment: Just to confirm this also works for C# .NET Standard templates.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `.vstemplate` file. What you need to do is edit it so that VS knows that there is supposed to be additional files. Unzip the file that was exported, add the files you want, then open the `.vstemplate` file. The part of the `.vstemplate` you should change is between the `<TemplateContent>` tags:

```
    <TemplateContent>
                <Project TargetFileName="project.vcxproj" File="project.vcxproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
                    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="$projectname$.vcxproj.filters">project.vcxproj.filters</ProjectItem>
                    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="file1.cpp">file1.cpp</ProjectItem>
                    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="file2.h">file2.h</ProjectItem>
                    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="input.txt">input.txt</ProjectItem>
                </Project>
    </TemplateContent>
```

This tells VS to add the files `file1.cpp`, `file2.h` and `input.txt` to the project when you make it. Just change the names to the files you want, save everything and rezip the folder.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I just put the source within it, ...I've had luck exporting code from github because it contains multiple projects...
It's this stupid thing ... under Project Dependencies "The Project Dependencies option is only available in a solution with more than one project" so I have no option to select the source. ...they made it like this on purpose but I don't know why.