# Template for other projects asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Let's say I have a project that is simply a template for other projects I want to create. I want all my projects to look the same and so on. I have already made this template and I want to copy it into new solution. But its not really that easy. I tried to use Project -> Export template. But that is not really working either, it does not copy controllers or css. Do you have any "easy" alternative ?
Thanks for answers.

Comment: A NuGet package is probably your best bet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exported project template in VS2017 misses source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553375/exported-project-template-in-vs2017-misses-source-files)

Comment: Why not just create a started project that can be used as a base for others with full source?

Comment: It seems it is a [known problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/77773/vs-2017-%E9%92%88%E5%AF%B9-aspnet-core-%E5%AF%BC%E5%87%BA%E6%A8%A1%E7%89%88%E5%8A%9F%E8%83%BD%E6%9C%89%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98.html) and a fix is currently pending release (currently marked for the 15.8.3 release!?!?)